# How do I specify the Username / Password for my SMTP in the Email Trace Listener used by the MS Entriprise Library Logging Block?

Tags: asp.net, smtp, enterprise-library, logging-application-block

I'm using Enterprise Library 4.1 and I've configured the Logging Application Block to log my errors in my ASP.NET MVC 3 application.  Everything works just fine and my errors are currently written to a log.

I'd like to also email the errors to myself but we use Google Apps and its SMTP server requires a username / password.

Here's the listener I've added for Email logging I'm hoping I just need to add some kind of username="" and password="" attributes.  Anybody know what they are?

```
  <loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="true">
    <listeners>
      <add toAddress="my@email.com" fromAddress="my@email.com"
        subjectLineStarter="" subjectLineEnder="" smtpServer="smtp.gmail.com" 
        smtpPort="587" formatter="" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.EmailTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.EmailTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        name="Email" />
    </listeners>
```

I should note that it looks lie EmailTraceListnerData does have a "userName" and "password" property in Enterpise Library 5.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee762316(v=PandP.50).aspx.  But it doesn't seem to apply to 4.1.  Anybody know a workaround?

Comment: Ent Lib 5 uses userName and password.  I'd assume it's the same for 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justin, we've added authentication to the EmailTraceListener in v5.0. If you must stay on 4.1, see the workarounds [here](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/57165?ProjectName=entlib).